Can I Use the Wait/Sleep Element in a Platform Event Triggered Flow?
I have this platform event triggered flow that listens for a JSON message sent from an
external system that contains an array of objects (contacts with updated field values).
This flow:

Parses a JSON message from an external system to an apex defined variable to use in the flow.
Puts the contact ids found from the JSON message in a collection and then gets all the contacts in my orgs where their ids are in that collection.
Loop through the apex defined variable (outer loop) and then the collection of the matching contacts from my Org (inner loop) and try to match the current contact from the apex defined variable to the one currently selected from my contacts in my org
If they match then we just transfer the field values from my apex defined variable contact to the fields on my matched contact and then add that updated contact to a collection to get mass updated once the loops went through their collections.

I have tried to optimize my flow the best I can when it comes to SOQL/DML but when trying large messages with 50+ contacts seem to fail with Apex CPU time limit exceeded errors on a decision node trying to match contact ids I got from the external system to the ones in my Org.
The decision node is in a nested for loop so it makes sense to me why with a lot of contacts that would fail but with 10 contacts it works fine.
Is there a way in a platform event triggered flow to implement a wait/sleep function so it process 10 contacts at a time, or would I need to convert this flow to Batch Apex?


Not sure it works in the context you have here, but calling an invocable method allows you to start a new transaction (see advanced settings on the element).
